# Pass html form input as argument for python function (recommender system)

Tags: python, html, flask, keras, data-science

I have built a recommender system using a Keras CNN. I am deploying it with Flask as a web application. Currently it displays images in the form of a gallery. I want to use html form to click the image and then generate recommendations from the image clicked.

I am using `PIL` to pass into the model. So far everything works fine, I'm a bit stuck on how to make it pass into the function and return the results. Thank you!  I'm new and this is my first go around with Flask.

Tried several ways to pass the form, however not sure if I have been doing it the correct way.

Also have tried several variations on the function.
I want to pass the image clicked into my python function, then return back the related images. So far I have this for `index.html`:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}" method="POST">
     <div class="gallery">
        {% for image in images %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> <img 
             src="static/img/{{ image }}"></button>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</form>
#Here is my recommender function:

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product = request.form['product']

        # compute cosine similarities between images
        cosine = cosine_similarity(imgs_features)

        # creates a dataframe of the cosine similarites
        cosine_df = pd.DataFrame(cosine, columns=products, 
        index=products)

        sim_images = 5

        p_name = os.path.basename(str(product))
        image = load_img(product, target_size=(img_size, img_size))
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.show()
        recommend_imgs = cosine_df[product].sort_values(ascending=False) 
        [1:sim_images + 1].index
        for i in range(0, len(recommend_imgs)):
            image = load_img(recommend_imgs[i], target_size=(img_size, 
            img_size))
            # plt.imshow(image)
            # plt.show()
            rec_name = os.path.basename(str(recommend_imgs[i]))
        return render_template('results.html', name=product, 
        res=rec_name, pred_imgs=plt.imshow(image))
```

I get this error mostly:

> werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap..newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'product'

Along with:

```
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to start the function. I am not sure how to pass the image value that you need to the form, unless each image as a specific value name you can pass it to the function.

Html:

```
{% for image in images %}

<form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}" method="POST">

    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="{{ image.value}}"> 

      <img src="static/img/{{ image }}">

    </button>

</form>

{% endfor %}
```

python:

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit'] == '<image.value_1>':
            # do something
            ...


        elif request.form['submit'] == '<image.value_2>':
            # do something
            ...
        ...
```

well, that's all.